# Как сделать самонаводящиеся пули в Unity 2D?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

У меня такая проблемка, очень хочу в игру добавить самонаводку, но не могу понять как это сделать и не жрать оптимизацию. У меня в игре может быть хоть 100 врагов на экране и нужно чтобы пуля самонаводилась к ближайшему врагу. Я пытался это сделать через for и проверку расстояния врага от персонажа,оно работает,но я быстро откинул эту идею, ведь каждый кадр будет идти эта проверка над сотней ото и больше объектов.

Есть ли способ легче это сделать?

Как это устроено в том же Soul Knight где вообще все огнестрельные оружия самонаводятся или в айзеке.